# How to address column names and column contents of R dataframe using variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, subset

I have the following dataframe created as:

`A <- data.frame(Col1 = c("Item1","Item1","Item1","Item2","Item2","Item2","Item1","Item1","Item2","Item2"), Col2 = 101:110)`

[image]

Now, I need to create a new dataframe with the condition that it should only include all items of the *dataframe A* where the value of *Col1 = "Item2"*. That is, I need to get the following:

[image]

Traditionally, I can do this simply as follows:

```
A_new <- A[A$Col1=="Item2",]
```

(OR)

```
A_new <- A['$'(A,Col1)=="Item2",]
```

But rather, I need to do do this via variable names instead, owing to the nature of my actual code.
So I define two variables as follows:

```
var1 <- "Col1"
var2 <- "Item2"
```

And now when I try to create this new dataframe using the following, I simply get an empty dataframe with the two columns and no rows:

```
A_new <- A['$'(A,var1)==var2,]
```

And also, when I apply this exact same logic on my actual code trying to create the subset dataframe, I additionally get an error saying my *var1* is `invalid subscript type 'language'`

***Can anyone help me out with creating this subset dataframe by addressing column names and column contents using variables?***

Comment: You can use `[` or `[[` with variables names - `A[A[[var1]] == var2, ]`, or `A[A[, var1] == var2, ]`

Comment: This is working perfect. Thanks a lot!